# How to optimize my code with react, redux-toolkit and react-hook-form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-toolkit, react-hook-form

LANGUAGE : javascript (with react, redux toolkit, react hook form)

So i have an application with a form.
The form have multiple step and multiple data who are depenting from each other.
The user can naviguate between step and can save at any time

I've used react-hook-form to dispatch my data every time a value change.

```
  const data = watch()

 useEffect(() => {
dispatch(
  fetchUserData({
    name: data.name,
    price: data.price,
    number: data.number,
    langue: data.langue,
  })
);

dispatch(
  fetchOtherData({
    introduction: data.introduction,
    price: data.price,
    hour: data.hour, 
    profile: data.profile, 
    reduction: data.reduction, 
      })
    );
  }, [data, dispatch]);
```

But now, i have more than 20 dispatch a the first load of my application (because of the watch)

Is there a better way to do ? I can't use "onSubmit" because of the dependencies of my data with each other.

Comment: I think you do not need to store your values in redux. You have two requirements here. First one user can save values anytime. You can get all the form values using `getValues` method from `useForm` hook. Second, you data is dependent. You do not need to watch all values. You can only watch for only dependent value or multiple values by passing the name of field in watch like this watch('field1') or multiple values `watch(['field1','field2', ...])`. Please read the docs for more info. https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/watch

Comment: That's a good answer :) I will review my code to apply what you say, thank you

Comment: Just want to thank you, the getValues method is great, don't have multiple dispatch problem anymore :)